# Where is @android:drawable looking for?

Tags: android, android-drawable

When I try to use default Android icons, I use:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_"
```

And on Android Studio, if I hit `ctrl-space`, I get a list of availables `ic_` icons.
I suppose they come from android-sdks folder but, if yes,  where exactly?
As my targetSdkVersion="22", I supposed I could find these icons, and add more ones from https://github.com/google/material-design-icons, in `android-sdks/platforms/android-22/data/res/`, where I can find drawable-xhdpi and all others, but obviously, it doesn't seem to be the case.
http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android doesn't help me much on how to use it.
Any help?

Comment: you should not be accessing the android drawables that way. It is recommended you copy them into your project because they can be deleted/renamed in a later version.

Comment: @tyczj that's what i wanted to say too. and also don't add your own images there, use your app resource folder

Comment: @tyczj "because they can be deleted/renamed in a later version" -- ones defined in `android.R.drawable` are reasonably safe; it would be somewhat surprising if Google got rid of those, due to backwards compatibility requirements. However, unless *all* your icons can be satisfied via `android.R.drawable` icons, it is better to use ones directly in your project, so you control their exact look and feel (e.g., to match the other icons that you design yourself or get from other sources).

Comment: @tyczj, you may be right but Google itself often use that way in their examples. Maybe for simplicity from their side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I suppose they come from android-sdks folder but, if yes, where exactly?

The IDE code-completion hopefully comes from what is [in `android.R.drawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html) for the `compileSdkVersion` you are using. The actual images can be found in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/$VERSION/data/res/`, where `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever your Android SDK is installed and `$VERSION` is a directory based on your `compileSdkVersion` (e.g., `android-22`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Ok thanks, this is what I though, anyway Android Studio is far to propose all ic_ icons (74 icons) I can see in, for example, android-22/data/res/drawable-hdpi (165 icons). any idea?

Comment: @caBBAlainB: The rest of those icons are not part of the Android SDK, in terms of what we can use from within our apps via `android.R.drawable` references.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ok so these ones must be copied in the project's folders.

Comment: @caBBAlainB: Correct, just as if they were icons from some external source.